# KTor is terminating GET requests when responses take longer than requestReadTimeoutSeconds

Tags: netty, ktor

We have some long requests (fetching too much data, but long story) that are getting terminated by KTor (Netty engine) based on the value of `requestReadTimeoutSeconds`. These are GET requests, so no body to be sent.

It was set to 25 and the request is terminated after 25 seconds, and I changed it to 15 seconds then it started to terminating after 15 seconds.

Even though the response is large, we make sure that we start streaming back the results "immediately". I can also see from the client that we start receiving content, but the connection is terminated.

Am I wrong in assuming that `requestReadTimeoutSeconds` should not affect GET requests. It should not time out after receiving the body on other requests? Or maybe there is no way to figure out when the client is "done" receiving?

Thanks,
Anders

Answer (score 4):

The `requestReadTimeoutSeconds` maps directly to `ReadTimeoutHandler`(https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html) from Netty: so it's the way to configure `Netty` internals.

The official netty docs say:

```
Raises a ReadTimeoutException when no data was read within a certain period of time.
```

The timeout refers to network reads, so it's expected behavior.

The thing you can do here is to write a custom feature:
For example:

```kotlin
class Timeouts {
    class Config(var postRequestTimeout: Long = 5000L)

    companion object : ApplicationFeature<ApplicationCallPipeline, Config, Unit> {
        override val key: AttributeKey<Unit> = AttributeKey("Timeouts")

        override fun install(pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline, configure: Config.() -> Unit) {
            val postTimeout = Config().apply(configure).postRequestTimeout
            if (postTimeout <= 0) return

            pipeline.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features) {
                if (call.request.httpMethod != HttpMethod.Post) return@intercept

                withTimeout(postTimeout) {
                    proceed()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/e5l/31bcf22a813008bd7418b5c944b225c9

And install it with:

```kotlin
install(Timeouts) {
   postRequestTimeout = 5000 // in ms
}
```

This feature allows you to set the timeout for post requests directly.

We will be happy if you describe the use cases you have here in a feature request: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. But, this imposes a timeout for the entire transaction, not just the client sending content. Any idea how to do that? :)